# OpenCV object detecting and save videofile

Tags: python, opencv

I want to object detect and save the video, but the video saved only 6kb or 0kb and it can't be play

If there is no this line

```
x, y, width, height, area = stats[index]
```

it will be saved

Do you know why And is there a solution?

```
import cv2
import time
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("rtsp://admin:admin@128.1.1.110:554")

width = int(cap.get(3))
height = int(cap.get(4))
fcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
recording = False

fgbg = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2(varThreshold=200, detectShadows=0)

while(1):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    hms = time.strftime('%H_%M_%S', time.localtime())

    fgmask = fgbg.apply(frame)

    nlabels, labels, stats, centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(fgmask)

    for index, centroid in enumerate(centroids):
        if stats[index][0] == 0 and stats[index][1] == 0:
            continue
        if np.any(np.isnan(centroid)):
            continue

        x, y, width, height, area = stats[index]
        centerX, centerY = int(centroid[0]), int(centroid[1])

        if area > 200:
            cv2.circle(frame, (centerX, centerY), 1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + width, y + height), (0, 0, 255))
            cv2.putText(frame, str(area), (centerX, y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 255, 255))

    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)

    k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xff
    if k == ord('r') and recording is False:
        path = 'test_' + str(hms) + '.avi'
        print('recording start')
        writer = cv2.VideoWriter(path, fcc, 30.0, (width, height))
        recording = True

    if recording:
        writer.write(frame)

    if k == ord('e'):
        print('recording end')
        recording = False
        writer.release()

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this will solve your problem

```
# importing the module 
import cv2 
import numpy as np
  
# reading the vedio 
source = cv2.VideoCapture(0)  // add your URL insed of "0"

# We need to set resolutions. 
# so, convert them from float to integer. 
frame_width = int(source.get(3)) 
frame_height = int(source.get(4))
recording = False
fcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
   
size = (frame_width, frame_height) 

fgbg = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2(varThreshold=200, detectShadows=0)
result = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi', fcc, 30, size) 
  
# running the loop 
while True: 
  
    # extracting the frames 
    ret, frame = source.read() 

    fgmask = fgbg.apply(frame)
    nlabels, labels, stats, centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(fgmask)

    for index, centroid in enumerate(centroids):
        if stats[index][0] == 0 and stats[index][1] == 0:
            continue
        if np.any(np.isnan(centroid)):
            continue

        x, y, width, height, area = stats[index]
        centerX, centerY = int(centroid[0]), int(centroid[1])

        if area > 200:
            cv2.circle(frame, (centerX, centerY), 1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + width, y + height), (0, 0, 255))
            cv2.putText(frame, str(area), (centerX, y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 255, 255))

    # displaying the video 
    cv2.imshow("Live", frame) 

    k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xff
    if k == ord('r') and recording is False:
        print('recording start')
        recording = True

    if recording:
        result.write(frame)

    if k == ord('e'):
        print('recording end')
        recording = False
        result.release()

# closing the window 
cv2.destroyAllWindows() 
source.release()
```

But unfortunately, I can not hms with the output file name.
That can try your self
If helpful this for you give

Comment: thank you for answer
i use
`result = [cv2.VideoWriter('output1.avi', fcc, 30, size), cv2.VideoWriter('output2.avi', fcc, 30, size)]`

but this way is created at the beginning of the file and cannot be named with a time.

Comment: When using the result function inside the while loop it gives 6kb video file because it looping always and when we stop the recording it saved the last shot of a video. So it always gives the output as a 6kb video file

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you need to delete some codes.

```
cv2.imshow('MultiTracker', frame)

  # quit on ESC button
  if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == 27:  # Esc pressed
    break
  # k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xff  
    
  #if k == ord('r') and recording is False:
  #  print('recording start')
  #  recording = True

  #if recording:
  result.write(frame)

  #if k == ord('e'):
  #  print('recording end')
  #  recording = False
  #  result.release()
result.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cap.release()
```

it works for me, the reason why it is 6kb is you start write but not append frame to output avi file.